# Including a file with absolute path

Tags: external-files, paths

I have a python script which compiles a tex file on my D drive. I would like to include a data file into my tex file. This data file is located on the following directory on Windows:

```
\\filesrv\xxx-sc\C_Data\XYZ_Cal\XYZ_C_Cer\filename.csv
```

I tried the following:

```
\DATA{filenameTable}{//filesrv/xxx-sc/C\_Data/XYZ\_Cal/XYZ\_C\_Cer/filename.csv}
```

I can include the data file when it is located in the parent directory ({./XXXX/filename.csv}) but I have to save on the given directory.

Comment: The `\_` is probably the culprit. (`\` is not just "escape this character" in LaTeX, it's more complex. Read TeXbook if you want, although most people don't) Try moving it to some directory that does not have any space or underscore in its name and try again.

Comment: thanks a lot, you were right. first I tried to save it in a directory with no underscore and now it also worked only with underscore instead of \_

Comment: Also please write a minimal working example (maybe next time). See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means. For now I've no idea what your `\DATA` command is.

Comment: TeX is generally only allowed to write in the directory containing the main file or below it, for security concerns.

Comment: Yes I will do that next time. Basically I could have described the \DATA command which includes data from files. This time it was to complicate to create a min reproducible example because I have around 15 different files and a huge class file:) anyway thanks!